# Human body part HAAR Cascade classifier

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to detect different body parts from an image. It is similar to the face detection classifier provided in openCV. I tried training and making my own classifier to detect human hand, leg, torso and etc. They are providing lot of false positive. Has anyone created body part classifier? I will really appreciate if anyone can share it.

Comment: How are you planning on getting high enough resolution to differentiate between a leg and an arm using HAAR. - you have to remember that it basically uses squares to identify parts of the image. I'm not sure you could ever identify a difference between an arm and a leg using HAAR.

An arm and a Torso should be more doable though...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure HAAR is the best approach. I would try to somehow use the filters of the "person" model in latent svm detector or better -  use the latent svm detector to detect the whole body and then check where the filters for the different body were fitted.

latent-svm
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

Answer (score 0):

I used 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' for face detection.
Tried and wrote code of Torso Image Classifier(in Python) can be work for other human body part image classifier.

Main#

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
from body import torso

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    scale_percent = 79 # percent of original size
    width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)

    resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        #rectangle face
        cv2.rectangle(resized,(x,y),(x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        face_start = (x,y)
        face_end = (x+w, y+h)

        #rectangle torso
        torso_xy = torso(face_start,face_end) 
        # cv2.rectangle(resized,((x-30, y+h)),(face_end[0]+30, face_end[1]+100), (0,122,0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(resized,torso_xy[0],torso_xy[1], (0,122,0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('img',resized)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**body.py**

```
import os

def torso(face_start,face_end):
    mid_face_x = int((face_start[0] + face_end[0]) / 2)
    mid_face_y = int((face_start[1] + face_end[1]) / 2)

    face_width_x= face_end[0] - face_start[0]
    face_height_y= face_end[1] - face_start[1]

    start_torso = (
    (mid_face_x-face_width_x), (face_end[1]+int(face_end[1]*0.05))
    )

    end_torso = (
    (mid_face_x+face_width_x), (face_end[1]+int(face_height_y*3))
    )
    return ((start_torso,end_torso))
```

[image: Human Torso Image Classifier]